# Executing program on remote Jenkins fails

Tags: maven, jenkins, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I have Jenkins setup with master and one slave. Both machines are CentOS6.

On the master environment looks like this:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/default/bin:/root/bin
# rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.4.2.3
# which rpmbuild
/usr/bin/rpmbuild
```

On the slave environment looks like this:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
# rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.8.0
# which rpmbuild
/usr/bin/rpmbuild
```

I am using rpm-maven-plugin version 2.1.5. When I run the build with goal `rpm:attached-rpm` on the master it works great. But when I run it on the slave it fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.5:attached-rpm (default) on project netvizura-linux: Unable to build the RPM: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "rpmbuild" (in directory "/usr/jenkins/workspace/netvizura-linux/target/rpm/netvizura-linux/SPECS"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running under different users on master and slave?

Comment: what are the permissions on /usr/bin/rpmbuild ?

Comment: in the configuration file for maven, try using the absolute path to rpmbuild: instead of doing `rpmbuild my.spec`, use `/usr/bin/rpmbuild my.spec`

Comment: what is special about '/usr/jenkins/workspace/netvizura-linux/target/rpm/netvizura-linux/SPECS'  that it exists on master and not on the slave?

Comment: I have to apologize to everyone - we are in the middle of release, so I cannot dedicate the time to answer to your questions. I restricted the build to master and will investigate further in 2 weeks.

Comment: Uh, it's strange that this question is attracting negative votes. I'll close it since I'm no longer responsible for the server in question.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have rpmbuild bin installed in slave host, install with `# yum install rpm-build -y`

Comment: Obviously it is installed, but with different version. Look closely at what I have written.
Honestly, I kept doing RPM packaging on master server for now. We really don't have the time to investigate this issue further.

Comment: For Ubuntu: `# apt install rpm`